# Sorting out an install script after being disconnected from server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, vps, ubuntu-server

I'm pretty new to linux...

I was running an install script for something on my ubuntu vps and I got disconnected from the server. I'm able to log back in again but I'm worried this install script might be waiting for prompts in the background.

What's the best action to take in this situation? Should I just run the script again, or should I do some kind of cleanup first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disconnect (from the terminal), the install script receives a signal (SIGHUP) which usually leads to program termination. If it is stuck, you probably should kill and re-run it, but there is no 100% confidence it will work.

Next time use `screen`. If you disconnect, you can then reconnect to the running screen instance using `screen -dr`. It has many other features you can read about in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or numerous [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=gnu+screen+tutorial).